# Make an dropdown menu css with php items

Tags: html, css

Im walking in s problem because im making an dropdown menu. But the website is almost only written in PHP

What i have now is http://jsfiddle.net/rick043/cFz7q/

The drop down menu needs to be on the Language button. But i have no clue how to do this.

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Language</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><?php include("sc_language.php"); ?></a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/L9v2S/) - now it will work when hovering over the `li` containing the `ul`.

Change the following:

```
#nav ul li: hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

To:

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Part of it wasn't working because there was a space between `li: hover`. You also needed to add `position:absolute` so the dropdown `ul` wouldn't affect the flow of the other elemenets.